# Decoding HTML text in C#

Tags: c#, html, .net, unit-testing, nunit

I have a helper method:

```
public static string StripHtml(this string text)
{
    text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(text);
    text = Regex.Replace(text, @"<(.|\n)*?>", "");

    return text;
}
```

And a unit test:

```
[Test]
public void StripHtmlConvertsNbspEntityIntoSpace()
{
    string result = "A&nbsp;B".StripHtml();
    Assert.AreEqual("A B", result);
}
```

When I run the unit test, it fails with the following error:

```
 String lengths are both 3. Strings differ at index 1.
  Expected: "A B"
  But was:  "A B"
  ------------^
```

So my question is, why `&nbsp;` was not decoded into a space character?

Comment: Non-breaking space is not the same as space. :)

Comment: Nice name for method. Make it dance also :)

Comment: @lazyberezovsky, not yet :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

&nbsp gets decoded into a non-breaking-space character, not a space character, looks for the user the same but is another character.

If you press alt+255 it's the non-breaking-space alt+32 it's the norman space if you want to look at it.

You can save the text output and look at it in an hex editor, there you should notice that it got another hex value than a normal space

Comment: Thanks! I've added `text = Regex.Replace(text, @"\u00A0", " ");` inside `StripHtml` method and it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

is a different character than space. The unit test is correct.
see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_character

Answer (score 0):

The HTML entity   doesn't represent a space, it represents a non-breaking space.
The non-breaking space has character code 160:
string nbspace = "\u00A0";

the non-breaking space is simply not a space, so if you want a space instead you have to replace it

```
var text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("A&nbsp;B"));
text = Regex.Replace(text, @"<(.|\n)*?>", "");
byte[] c = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text.ToString());
byte[] x = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("A B");
```